# Can't remove a line from conf file

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor

When I build my ktor project It fails and it tells me about a line which causes the failure. The line is located in the application.conf file:

```
ktor {

development = true


    deployment {
        //the problem is with "heroku logs --tail"
        port = 8080heroku logs --tail
        port = ${?PORT},
        watch = [ classes, resources ]
    }
    application {
        modules = [ com.example.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
}
```

When I try to remove the line and then build the project it returns back again.
How can I remove it?

Comment: looks like you're modifying this file with some script, first of all try using grep command with "heroku logs" text, if this didn't help try disabling gradle plugins or other gradle code parts one by one to find the reason - anything contain heroku in name is under suspicion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by not removing the whole sentence but removing a part of it and then build the server. Then remove the other part and build the server again. The line will no longer return back.